# XML response is not getting parsed in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, rest

I am getting an XML response from an API using requests library in python. But when I parse the response in python as per accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482088/python-how-to-parse-xml-response-and-store-a-elements-value-in-a-variable) . I am using the following code for it.

```
    try:
        # Prepare request 
        payload = "<DataRequest><groupcode>ABC</groupcode><employeeno>123456</employeeno></DataRequest>"
        url = config['SF_Credentials']['end_point']
        headers = {"Authorization": config['SF_Credentials']['authorization'], "Content-Type":"text/xml"}
        response = requests.post(url, data = payload, headers= headers)
        if response.status_code >300:
            print('error in getting ecard', response.text)

        xml_data = ET.fromstring(response.text)
        print(dir(xml_data), xml_data.text)
        print('done')    
    except Exception as e:
        print('exception in getting ecard', e)
```

but `print(xml_data.text)` gives output None.
My API response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocumentElement><EcardInformation>https://integration.medibuddy.in/MediAssistAPI/DownloadEcard/4021172954/name/123</EcardInformation></DocumentElement>'
```

I am using post call unlike the question referred above. Does that make any difference in this case? or there is something else I am missing?
Also, the output of `response.text` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocumentElement><EcardInformation>https://integration.medibuddy.in/MediAssistAPI/DownloadEcard/4021172954/Name/1234</EcardInformation></DocumentElement>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: print the value of `response.text`. If it is None it means the question is not about XML parsing, It is about calling the API properly.

Comment: response.text is giving proper output. I have already checked it

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocumentElement><EcardInformation>https://integration.medibuddy.in/MediAssistAPI/DownloadEcard/4021172954/name/123</EcardInformation></DocumentElement>'
` Is this is the response?

Comment: yes. I have edited the question with response.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below (The parsing works well)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <DocumentElement>
            <EcardInformation>https://integration.medibuddy.in/MediAssistAPI/DownloadEcard/4021172954/name/123</EcardInformation>
        </DocumentElement>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
ecard_info = root.getchildren()[0]
print(ecard_info.text)
```

output

```
https://integration.medibuddy.in/MediAssistAPI/DownloadEcard/4021172954/name/123
```

Comment: thanks. I was not considering the children and was treating the whole tree wrongly.